# Send email by unique identifier, grouped by ID #

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

i am stuck with this. What i am trying to do is to loop each ID and group them by Support Contact and email those person with respect to ID, it could be a sentence or table in the body of the email.

> ```
> ID      Support Name Support Contact Decision
> MN-888  Qwe          qwe@yahoo.com   Yes
> MN-111  Asd          asd@yahoo.com   Yes
> MN-999  Qwe          qwe@yahoo.com   Yes
> MN-034  Ppp          ppp@yahoo.com   Yes
> ```

Desired output:

Dear Qwe,

Please return ID # MN-888, MN-999

Code where i got stuck

```
Sub Test1()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("C").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value) = "yes" Then

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Reminder"
            .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value _
                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Please return ID # " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _

            .Send  'Or use Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
    Next cell
cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `For Each cell In Columns("C")....` this line will send same mail multiple time if it has same email in column C.

Comment: @Harun24HR is there alternative code that will only send one time, so if qwe@test.com has 2 id, it will send 1 mail containing the 2 ids

Comment: Code can be written but I suggest you use some formula to worksheet first. The formulas will pull unique values from column C and then gather all IDs for corresponding email to adjacent as comma separated. Then you can use same code to send mail. To get unique values use `UNIQUE()` formula and then use `TEXTJOIN()` to gather IDs.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i added you in facebook hoping that i can interact with you there @Harun24HR